# Unable to install ethereumjs-testrpc on AWS Cloud9 (Closed Issue)

Tags: testrpc, ethereumjs

I was able to install truffle and as a follow up was trying to install ethereumjs-testrpc on the Amazon AWS Cloud9 dev environment. While running the following install command

```
sudo npm install ethereumjs-testrpc
```

getting the following error log

```
    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'sync-exec'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/environment/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/lib/post_install.js:9:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414901085-0.9117075009271502/package/_baseZipObject.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.70-25.242.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/environment
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path /root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414901085-0.9117075009271502/package/_baseZipObject.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414901085-0.9117075009271502/package/_baseZipObject.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414896582-0.6147430951241404/package/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.9.70-25.242.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/environment
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path /root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414896582-0.6147430951241404/package/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /root/tmp/npm-7418-l8g4Ryqs/1518414896582-0.6147430951241404/package/node_modules/boom/lib/index.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/environment/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I can confirm that am using the node version v6.12.3 and also have tried steps mentioned at

[Amazon AWS Site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) and few [github links](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli/issues/134)

It would be great if i can some help on this.

Edit 1:

The actual issue was with the user permissions. What i did was create a new IAM user, gave it all required permissions, spun a new cloud9 instance and everything's working as expected.

Comment: You could get same functionality with ganache-cli if you can install it. It's testrpc itself, if that solves the problem

Comment: Thanks @1sn0s will try it if the testrpc install itself doesn't work. Did not want to deviate from the classic thing at this moment :)

Comment: First time npm install then sudo npm install ethereumjs-testrpc try it

Comment: @ALOMGIRHOSSEN can you expand your suggestion like on what are you suggesting to run npm install? I am just trying to install the testrpc npm package.

Comment: @1sn0s I see this message while installing testrpc, so your comment makes sense. 
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-testrpc@6.0.3: ethereumjs-testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue by creating a new IAM user and giving it required admin privileges in the aws IAM section and creating a new Cloud9 EC2 instance with the same user and installing the required packages.

Comment: Yep. The truffle team is maintaining testrpc now. Ganache is their tool name

Answer (score 0):

testrpc is written in Javascript and distributed as a Node package via npm. Make sure you have Node.js (>= v6.9.1) installed.

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

Having problems  [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc)

Comment: Thanks and i already had node and npm installed, but the issue was actually with the permissions.